# Algebraically closed concept

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $L$ is an extension field of $K$ and $L$ is algebraically closed. Then is it trivially true that $\forall f(x)\in K[x],~f(x)$ splits over $L$? I think the answer is yes since $L$ is algebraically closed means that every polynomial with coefficients in $L$ have a root in $L$ (and hence have all roots in $L$)

Comment: Yes, this follows by induction on the degree of $f$, starting with one root. So there is nothing to ask in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the splitting field of $f(x)\in K[x]$ must be contained in $L$ since $L$ is algebraically closed.